# Proving uniform continuity of function of two variables.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative

Proving uniform continuity of function:$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases} \frac{x^3-xy}{x^2+y^2},  & (x,y)\neq (0,0) \\ 0, & (x,y)=(0,0) \end{cases}$$

This is supposedly solve, but I don't understand the solution. It is proved that it is continuous and differentiable (asked in sub questions, but might be important for overall idea.) After this, it is proved that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)\leq 3$ and also $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)\leq 2$. Then it goes onto say: $$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq k \|x-y\|\\ 
  |f(x)-f(y)|\leq |f(x)-f(z)|+|f(z)-f(y)| \leq k \|x-z\|+ k \|z-y\|\\
   \leq k(\|x-z\|+ \|z-y\|)...$$

Does this make any sense? Im interested in this variation of the answer...

Comment: It would make a lot more sense if you didn't use $x$ and $y$ as both scalars and vectors in it. In any single piece of mathematics, a symbol should not be given more than one meaning.

Answer (score 2):

Forget about uniform continuity. That function is not even continuous at $(0,0)$: It tends to $0$ along the axes and $\to -1/2$ along the line $y=x.$ You can directly check that the partial derivatives are not bounded; for example $\partial f /\partial x (0,y) = -1/y,$ which blows up as $y\to 0.$

Answer (score -1):

Well you should always check carefully whether the function is continuous at point $(0,0)$ before going on.

If you take $y = x$ and $y = -x + x^2$ separately , you will find that the first limit is $-\frac12$ while the latter is $\frac12$, so it is not continuous at all

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).